# Display data by row (limited by 3) Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I'm new with programing.

I want to try to display element by row using angular and limited by 3 elements each row. (Using *ngFor)

For example, like this image
[3 element by row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P22fN.png)

I use Slice Pipe but this take only the 3 first element.

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of items | slice:0:3">
   {{ item }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Can anyone help me or show me an example of code

Answer (score 0):

In such grid cases, you need 2 loops. Here are two examples in form of table (vertical and horizontal directions)

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of items | slice:0:ceil(items.length/numberOfCols); let i=index;">
      <td *ngFor="let col of items | slice:0:numberOfCols; let j=index;">
        {{ items[ i*numberOfCols + j ] }}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<hr>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of items | slice:0:ceil(items.length/numberOfCols); let i=index;">
      <td *ngFor="let col of items | slice:0:numberOfCols; let j=index;">
        {{ items[ j*ceil(items.length/numberOfCols) + i ] }}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

ts:

```
items = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8'];
numberOfCols = 3;
ceil(x: number) {
    return Math.ceil(x);
}
```

if you using bootstrap or any other grid system (row - col), table can be replaced with div elements...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `*ngFor` and order the elements with `CSS Grid` with any rows or columns. Also, you can add `grid-auto-flow: column;` to order the elements in the columns.

```js
import {
  Component
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  public arr: number[] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
}
```

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: grid;
  gap: 10px;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, auto);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.element {
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div class="element" *ngFor="let element of arr">Element {{ element }}</div>
</section>
```

You can try this code on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ow68v9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

[image]